# Open 8 panes of TMUX and go to different directory in each one , and run a command in each pane?

Tags: command-line, tmux

Consider the code :

```
tmux new-session \; split-window -h \; split-window -v -p 66 \; split-window -v \; split-window -v \; select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -v -p 66 \; split-window -v -p 66 \; split-window -v \;
```

How can we add to this code the ability to open each pane in a different path `(cd ...)`  and also run a command in each pane : `npm run dev`

Comment: @guiverc: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following code in a script - works for me on Tmux 3.1:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a new session named "newsess", split panes and change directory in each
tmux new-session -d -s newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory1" Enter
tmux split-window -h -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory2" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 66 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory3" Enter
tmux split-window -v -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory4" Enter
tmux split-window -v -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory5" Enter
tmux select-pane -t newsess:0.0
tmux split-window -v -p 66 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory6" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 66 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory7" Enter
tmux split-window -v -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory8" Enter
# Set pane synchronization
tmux set-window-option -t newsess:0 synchronize-panes on
# Run command in all 8 panes
tmux send-keys -t newsess "npm run dev" Enter
# Attach to session named "newsess"
tmux attach -t newsess
```

For testing I'd recommend running `pwd` instead of whatever command you wish to run in 8 panes simultaneously (also to check directories are correct). ;-)

If you want to run different commands in each pane, you of course just run the command with `send-keys` after changing directory. But I was under the impression that you want to run the same command in each pane, and that's why pane synchronization would work.

Comment: Thanks , also can we run two commands in `tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory5" Enter` ? I want to run `cd && cd /path/to/directory{XXX}` in the same time

Comment: Yes I believe that would work. Please accept the answer when you have tested it works out for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tiny improvement;
If you want all panes to be equal size, the script becomes as following:

```
# Create a new session named "newsess", split panes and change directory in each
tmux new-session -d -s newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory1" Enter
tmux split-window -h -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory2" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 75 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory3" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 66 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory4" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 50 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory5" Enter
tmux select-pane -t newsess:0.0
tmux split-window -v -p 75 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory6" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 66 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory7" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 50 -t newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "cd /path/to/directory8" Enter
# Set pane synchronization
tmux set-window-option -t newsess:0 synchronize-panes on
# Run command in all 8 panes
tmux send-keys -t newsess "npm run dev" Enter
# Attach to session named "newsess"
tmux attach -t newsess
```